# Why we use group by in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

When we make a SQL request like this:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2, AGGR(*)
  FROM SomeTable
 GROUP BY attr1, attr2
```

for some aggregate function, we have to include a GROUP BY clause and list attr1 and attr2 in it.  My question is: why doesn't the SQL DBMS do it itself?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: 1) comma! 2) how would it know which fields to use?

Comment: google will provide you better answer i think

Comment: looks like sql client doesn't insert commas for you either

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Group By Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645815/sql-group-by-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you may want to group by `attr1`, `attr2` *and* `attr3`, even though you have no interest in the actual `attr3` value itself.

In other words, you may be required to group by the non-aggegated columns but this in only at a minimum. There's nothing preventing you from grouping by columns not actually included in the query.

And, since the query evaluator doesn't know what you wanted (or it wants you to follow the relevant standard), it may think it safer to insist you explicitly state it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with out `GROUP BY`, then you get the average from the whole table.
With `GROUP BY`, you get the average for each group.

Comment: I'm not sure if standard sql really allows queries like this without group by

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two functions type in sql - Single function & Group function . If you want to access the group data then you have to call 'Group by' function type .

For Example, Suppose you have a table of any organization with the column 'deptno' . Now if you want to count the 'no of employee' in each dept. then call count(*) ....group by deptno. 
The result will show the no of employee in each group .

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.